# ToyVPN Example with username and password credentials (PPTP)

Tags: android, android-studio, proxy, vpn, android-vpn-service

I have this ToyVpn sample project and I want to test it.
and in order to connect to the vpn the ToyVPN needs:
(Server IP, Server port, Shared Secret)

but the proxy format that I have is different:
(Server IP, port, username, password)
it is known as http & socks4 and socks5 proxies

I don't know what is the SharedKey, and if it's possible to implement a PPTP in ToyVPN in the first place.

I couldn't find anything online there is a big lack in this Proxy-VPN topic.

any help would be much appreciated.